# [karate/gatling]:Cannot find project Scala library 2.12.8 for module

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, karate

I want to run galtling tests using karate tests already in place.

For this I created a first .scala file and defined my pom.xml with the dependencies and plugins needed. I also downloaded the scala library at version 2.12.8

I encounter the following error: Cannot find project Scala library 2.12.8 for module. The library is not found.

My IDE is intelliJ. Here is the library I placed in my project

[image]

The library is integrated into the project module like this:

[image]

Here's the run/debug config:

[image]

Here's the scala.file:

```
package karate.features.api

import com.intuit.karate.gatling.PreDef._
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import scala.language.postfixOps
import scala.concurrent.duration._


class KarateGatling extends Simulation {

  val corpoProtocol = karateProtocol("/v0/corporations/{id}" -> Nil)
  val quotProtocol = karateProtocol("/v0/quotations/{id}" -> Nil)

  val createCorpo = scenario("blah").exec(karateFeature("classpath:karate/features/api/api-blah-blah.feature"))
  val createQuot = scenario("blah").exec(karateFeature("classpath:karate/features/api/api-v-blah.feature"))

  setUp(
    createCorpo.inject(rampUsers(20) during (10 seconds)).protocols(corpoProtocol),
    createQuot.inject(rampUsers(10) during (5 seconds)).protocols(quotProtocol)
```

Here's the pom.xml:

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.5.6
 

com.crm.e2e
e2e-ui
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
e2e-ui
Getting started with Karate

```
<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
    <junit-jupiter.version>5.4.0</junit-jupiter.version>
    <mockito.version>3.2.4</mockito.version>
    <karate.version>1.2.0</karate.version>
    <gatling.plugin.version>4.1.5</gatling.plugin.version>
    <scala.maven.plugin.version>4.5.6</scala.maven.plugin.version>
    <web-drivers.version>3.12.0</web-drivers.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-junit5</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-apache</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${web-drivers.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${web-drivers.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intuit.karate</groupId>
        <artifactId>karate-gatling</artifactId>
        <version>${karate.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>karate/**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.gatling</groupId>
            <artifactId>gatling-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${gatling.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <simulationsFolder>src/test/java</simulationsFolder>
                <includes>
                    <include>karate.features.api.perfCreateCorpo</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scala.maven.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-Jbackend:GenBCode</arg>
                            <arg>-Jdelambdafy:method</arg>
                            <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
                            <arg>-deprecation</arg>
                            <arg>-feature</arg>
                            <arg>-unchecked</arg>
                            <arg>-language:implicitConversions</arg>
                            <arg>-language:postfixOps</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My environment:

- IntelliJ 2022
- plugins cucumber+, KarateLab (free trial), scala, cucumber for scala
- ubuntu 20.04

How can I resolve the error please ?

Comment: yes, it is hard to get the scala support working in intellij. in the future we'd like to move it to java as the gatling team has recently made this an option. my advice is don't worry about this too much as you need to write very little gatling code when using karate. since your project is so complex, I can't help, my advice as always is to follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 2):

I fixed a simillar Intellij Maven Sync error:

> Cannot find project Scala library 2.12.14 for module

I added a configuration tag for Scala version to scala-maven-plugin in pom.xml

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <scalaVersion>2.12.14</scalaVersion>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```